# Finding unique combination of columns associated with 1 non-unique column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Here's my table:

| ItemID | ItemName | ItemBatch | TrackingNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | bag | 1 | 498239 |
| a | bag | 1 | 498239 |
| a | bag | 1 | 958103 |
| b | paper | 2 | 123444 |
| b | paper | 2 | 123444 |

I'm trying to find occurrences of ItemID + ItemName + ItemBatch that have a non-unique TrackingNumber.  So in the example above, there are 3 occurrences of `a bag 1` and at least 1 of those rows has a different TrackingNumber from any of the other rows.  In this case `958103` is different from `498239` so it should be a hit.

For `b paper 2` the TrackingNumber is unique for all the respective rows so we ignore this.  Is there a query that can pull this combination of columns with 3 identical fields and 1 non-unique field?

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab
WHERE ItemBatch IN (SELECT ItemBatch 
                    FROM tab 
                    GROUP BY ItemBatch, TrackingNumber
                    HAVING COUNT(TrackingNumber) = 1)
```

This query finds the combination of `(ItemBatch, TrackingNumber)` that occur only once, then gets all rows corresponding to their `ItemBatch` values.

Try it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=48c1c6a4d8f168e79e98983eb242b7a2).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```sql
SELECT
  t.ItemID,
  t.ItemName,
  t.ItemBatch,
  COUNT(*)
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY
  t.ItemID,
  t.ItemName,
  t.ItemBatch
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TrackingNumber) > 1;
```

Or if you want each individual row you can use a window function. You cannot use `COUNT(DISTINCT` in a window function, but you can simulate it with `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX`

```sql
SELECT
  t.*
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      Count = MAX(dr) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ItemID, t.ItemName, t.ItemBatch)
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.ItemID, t.ItemName, t.ItemBatch ORDER BY t.TrackingNumber)
        FROM YourTable t
    ) t
    
) t
WHERE t.Count > 1;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=271e0802148533805a9820aed23218e4)

Comment: As I understand "have a non-unique TrackingNumber", there should be `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TrackingNumber) > 1;`

Comment: You're right I missed that